# Idiom for doing everything oneself

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I am trying to find a generally acknowledged idiom for completing all steps of a task.

I have heard versions referring to comedy:

I did everything, *Premise, Setup and Punchline*

Volleyball:

I did everything, *Bump, Set and Spike*

Basketball:

I did everything, *Dribble, Pass and Dunk*

Are there more common ways of saying the above?

Comment: I don't understand the context. As a Brit, I'm not expected to understand basketball anyway, but surely *dribble, pass, **dunk*** is equivalent to *dribble, pass, **shoot*** in (non-American) ***football***. But if the "task" is ***to score*** (a "goal" in football, dunno what they all the equivalent in basketball), one player ***passes*** the ball to ***another*** player - who then attempts to score. You can't pass the ball to yourself - that makes no sense to me. Unless OP means that ***in the course of a game*** (or "playing career") he *can* adopt many different roles at different times,.

Comment: The question is clear even if the detailed meanings of the examples are not known to me. “Bell, book and candle” and “lump , stock and barrel” come to my  own mind but will be obscure to others. With so many phrases already available to us, the request for a generally understood idiom seems reasonable. Leave oopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lock, stock, and barrel** (adv. (and adj.)) = in its entirety.

OED

> **P7. lock, stock, and barrel** *(In early evidence in figurative contexts, with reference to the parts of a gun.)* **a. As a whole; entirely, completely.**
>
> 1905   Times 7 July 10/3   *[Sir George White said:] He was not a
> Scotsman; he was..lock, stock, and barrel an Irishman.*
>
> 2014   Aberdeen Evening Press (Nexis) 3 Feb. 24   *We have already sold our soul, lock stock and barrel, to the oil industry.*
>
> (Adj) 1999   F1 Racing Nov. 51/2   *‘I will remain as chairman..’, he says, before rattling off his views about his team's lock-stock-and-barrel sale to Ford.*

Answer (score 0):

There are a few phrases that spring to mind.
**Lock, stock and barrel** (the parts of a gun) is fairly common saying in the UK.
This is very similar to the American saying **Soup to nuts.**
**Fiercely independent** describes someone who rejects outside help.
**Solo performance** might fit.
Some might quote the Frank Sinatra song **I did it my way**.
If the action is seen to be showing off then **grandstanding** or **upstaging**
The exact phrase used depends on context and circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

[Jack-of-all-trades](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jack-of-all-trades) may be another (but not exact) option.

> The small forward does everything on the basketball court and needs to have a well-rounded set of skills. You could call him a **Jack of all trades**. He handles the ball some, rebounds, shoots from the outside, the inside, and plays defense on the perimeter and inside. [source](https://www.ducksters.com/sports/basketball/small_forward.php)

Answer (score 0):

**I was the chief/head cook and bottle washer.**

> A person who is the chief cook and bottle washer is in charge but also
> performs many duties, some of them trivial; someone in charge of
> almost every job ....
>
> - *My father always tells new customers he is the chief cook and bottle washer. He owns a book store.*
> - *At my old job I was basically the chief cook and bottle washer. There was not much I didn’t do.*

[[Idioms Online](https://www.idioms.online/chief-cook-and-bottle-washer/)]